# Video streaming server and storage

Tags: video, streaming, storage, bandwidth

quick question. Any help greatly appreciated.

I am thinking of streaming video from a streaming server. Is it possible to store the videos on a separate server? What are the pros and cons of this?

Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some streaming services such as Ooyala and Brightcove.

Answer (score 0):

You can store streaming videos using DVRs as separate server. You can either make your own DVR program or get some commercially available one. There would be some performance impact if you want to do this in real-time, since uploading to another server will take some some.